# Hotlinking photos from Facebook - an "ok" practice?

Tags: facebook, hotlinking

For my current website project, I wanted to off-load some bandwidth as well as data management to facebook - by this I mean:

1. Use a public Facebook page as 3rd party host for images to use for our website (screenshots, info-graphics, etc) , thereby offloading GUI/programming work for uploading , organizing and managing photos.
2. directly hotlink images from facebook (no need to use graph api) to our site thereby minimizing bandwidth consumption on our shared hosting account.

So i was wondering if this was an acceptible practice? I honestly am thinking this is a good idea..

It just require a bit more work for my site admins as, after uploading to facebook the image, they would have to right click the image and Copy the image link 
eg. 
[`http//fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/v/t1.0-9/10392502_885309924834069_6267758702284929640_n.jpg?oh=4696666945ebb7da0a1347c072cbb49c&oe=55507B7F&__gda__=1432842446_bdf59e5d4287fcd51a0016a40c13ce93`](http://http//fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/v/t1.0-9/10392502_885309924834069_6267758702284929640_n.jpg?oh=4696666945ebb7da0a1347c072cbb49c&oe=55507B7F&__gda__=1432842446_bdf59e5d4287fcd51a0016a40c13ce93)

and paste it into our website's image fields as necessary

I actually tested this and it seems to work pretty well too. I'm actually lovin it. (a whole lot less bandwidth consumption)

So i'm just wondering what you guys think of this practice?

Comment: facebook love it, they like tracking peoples web activity.

Comment: and i don't mind it. just glad facebook is not blocking hotlinks hehe

Comment: The CDN link is just temporary and will stop working after a while. So no it is not a good idea

Comment: @WizKid = awww really?! are you 100% on this? damn that would suck if so.

Comment: crap. alright thanks WizKid

Comment: I thought CDN links expire after the post linking the image (or video) resource is "deleted"? Awww this post was 2 years ago, not sure if its still relevant today.